# UIDatePicker Event Changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I write a simple iOS app just for learning, in my case I need to use a `UIDatePicker` and, after the user change the date, I need to write this date to an `UITextField`, here's the code:

.h File

```
@interface ExpenseViewController: UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *editTextDate;

- (void) updateTextFieldDate:(UIDatePicker *)pickerL;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ExpenseViewController

@synthesize ediTextDate;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [datePicker removeTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextFieldDate:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [editTextDate setInputView:datePicker];

}

- (void) updateTextFieldDate:(UIDatePicker *)pickerL{
    UIDatePicker *picker=(UIDatePicker*)self.editTextdate.inputView;
    editTextDate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
@end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ExpenseViewController updateTextFieldDate:]:unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d395f0
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Side note - there is no reason to declare the `updateTextFieldDate:` in the .h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code runs fine on my system, but I am getting exact same error when mistyping the method name in @selector(updateTextFieldDate:).

I know, stupid suggestion, but is it possible you have typo there in code, even if what you showed here doesn't have it? the typo in synthesize makes it look like you typed your class here instead of copy-pasting, so perhaps the xcode version has a typo in @selector part?

Comment: You're right.... i have typo the code.... when i see the code one more type i see what i do.... in the code on Xcode is: [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(upadteTextFieldDate:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; ------------------     but the correct is [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextFieldDate:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];                         ---- the selector name is incorrect... sorry guys....

Answer (score 1):

This is because textfield property `editTextDate` your are synthesizing is wrong as `ediTextDate`(means **t** is missing) so replace it with ** editTextDate**.

and replace your code

```
    UIDatePicker *picker=(UIDatePicker*)self.editTextdate.inputView; // wrong editTextdate , it is editTextDate
```

with this :

```
UIDatePicker *picker=(UIDatePicker*)self.editTextDate.inputView;
```

Then your code will work properly.

Hope it helps you.